# Wordpress wpdb insert & typecasting seems totally off

Tags: php, wordpress, casting

```
            $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='.str_replace(" ","",$postcode[$z]).',+UK&output=csv&sensor=false';

            $data = @file_get_contents($url);

            echo $data;

            $result = explode(",", $data);

            $lat = (float) $result[2]; // latitude
            $lon = (float) $result[3]; // longitude;

            echo '<br>Latitude: '.$lat;
            echo '<br>Longitude: '.$lon;                
            $wpresult = $wpdb->insert("buss_add",array(
                "buss_id" => $buss_id,
                "add1" => $add1[$z],
                "add2" => $add2[$z],
                "city" => $city[$z],
                "county" => $county[$z],
                "postcode" => $postcode[$z],
                "country" => $country[$z],
                "tel" => $tel[$z],
                "lat" => $lat,
                "lon" => $lon
            ),array(
                "%d","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%f","%f"
            ));
```

Despite this being right, and even with typecasting the lat and lon variables this does not seem to want to go into the database as a float. I think wordpress $wpdb is to blame. Anyone got any ideas?

To also confirm the database looks like this, which should be absolutely fine - http://cl.ly/421m2K3F2k3p3X1D3V1v

An example of the values below:

Latitude: 51.7191557
Longitude: 0.6665619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `$lat` is a string and `$z` is some number, then `$lat[$z]` is one char in that string, shouldn't you just use `"lat" => $lat` ?